# Can iOS scan for beacons in the background every 20-30 seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, core-bluetooth

My goal is to create an app that can do the following in the background:

- scan for beacons in the background
- collect all the beacon information
- do some calculation
- send data to the cloud server if internet is available
- go back to sleep

Is it possible to use `bluetooth-central` background mode and achieve this? Will my app be approved by apple later on if I do all this work in the background, registered only to this background service?

Comment: To scan for beacons you use CoreLocation, not CoreBluetooth.  Detection time can be up to a few minutes.  You can't control this.  Once you have detected a beacon in the background then everything else you want to do is possible

Comment: I need signal strength (rssi value of a beacon), and not exiting, entering proximity of a beacon....so I can calculate my position with some algorithm...I need those positions to be updated every minute or less...is that possible?

Comment: You still need to use CoreLocation for that.  It is called beacon ranging.  iOS filters iBeacon advertisements from CoreBluetooth, so you will not see any iBeacon advertisements using that framework.  Here are some articles on beacon ranging in the background  https://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html

Comment: I already managed to achieve beacon monitoring in the background. Problem is, at the moment, my monitoring is attached to background fetch background mode which is triggered every 15min-2h. I need something that can trigger beacon monitoring in the background in the range of 20sec-2min and still be approved by apple if possible.

Comment: You can start ranging based on beacon region entry, but beacon detection can take up to 15 minutes (although in my experience is is quicker than that). You can leave beacon region monitoring running indefinitely

Comment: What about `bluetooth-central` as trigger for beacon ranging+monitoring in the background? Is the app waken up each time BLE packet is received? Should that be more frequent than region entry/exit or background fetch?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116053/discussion-between-paulw11-and-aleksandar-lugonja).